# need help using/choosing excel function

Tags: excel, function, excel-2016

ive been trying to break into some excel just to get a little bit familiar with the program but im a little lost on some of the prebuilt functions. Here is one of the exercises ive been attemping.

*In cell B5 calculate the projected sales for January 2015. Use the Average 2014 Monthly Sales in B2 and the Growth Rate in cell B1. In cell C5, use appropriate cell referencing to calculate the projected sales for February 2015 based on the projected January sales and the Growth rate.*

[image]

which function would be best suited for this ?

Comment: You can delete it yourself but Scott would lose points below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a straight forward math problem

future amount = current amount + (current amount * percentage increase)

or simplified:

future amount = current amount * (1 + percentage increase)

in B5:

```
=B2*(1+B1)
```

Then in C5:

```
=B5*(1+$B$1)
```

And copy/drag across.  The B5 reference will change appropriately and it will fill in the correct amounts across.

---

You want a single formula for it all:

In B5 put:

```
=FVSCHEDULE($B$2,INDEX(($B$1*ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COLUMN(A:A))))/ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COLUMN(A:A))),))
```

And drag across.

Comment: I think there's a built in function to do the math.

Comment: thats what i was wondering to be honest. but thanks for the answer scott

Comment: @findwindow maybe, but I am unaware of such.  You may be able to use FV but it would be more work than this simple formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner well, if you don't know, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @findwindow not true I do not use financial formula often.

Comment: @JayD see edit for a single formula that will do it.

Comment: And no I will not be deleting this, I work hard to find a single formula that does what the OP wanted.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will be impressed when you get me that macro to do my laundry =P

Comment: @findwindow so would my wife.

Comment: @ScottCraner you can impress her by doing your own laundry =PP

Comment: @ScottCraner I apologize. That's too personal.

Comment: @findwindow she would have agreed with you.

Comment: @ScottCraner just tell her that God doesn't do laundry ~_^

Comment: @findwindow I will, and if you never here from me again it will be your fault.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will turn myself in to the police now.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Scott's original answer and it works really well in in this case.  I just want to expand on this as it appears to me to be a compound interest problem and finding out what the nth value of an investment is based on a fixed interest rate.  So a more general equation would be:

```
=P*(1+i)^(n)

P - Principal or starting value
i - Interest rate for the period (not annual unless you period is annual)
n - period number, 1 for first period 2 for 2nd etc.
```

Scott's formula works really well because all the months are side by side and there are no gaps.  This is what the OP presented to us in the example.  However,  if months had been missing a different approach would have been necessary.

An alternative approach using the OPs orignal setup could be:

```
=$B$2*(1+$B$1)^(COLUMN(A1))

B2 is the starting principal P
B1 is the interest for the period
COLUMN(A1) is a way to count the nth period as the formula is copied across.
```

If the date was stored in B4 and formatted to display a month, we could substitute the following for determining the n<sup>th</sup> period:

```
Month(B4)
```

Of course this assumes that the whole thing started in the first month, but an alternate form could be used to adjust the value based on a supplied starting month/date.

And of course the entire header row of month could simply be changed to an integer representing the n<sup>th</sup> period of interest

[image]

On a side note, one of the nice parts of using this method, is that it is independent of what is happening in adjacent cells.  Should a column in the middle of the series be erased, you will not be faced with a series of errors.

Comment: As I said I do not work with financial much.  This is much better than mine and should be the correct answer. @JayD

Comment: @ScottCraner K.I.S.S. This is a *slightly* more complex formula. Keep things simple and you have less to debug right? That is why your answer is better in my opinion.  This answer tossed in things that were not present originally and I only added it for someone stumbling across this in the future whose case it may fit better.  I did a search of the built in formulas for PMT, IMPT, FV, PV, but they all seemed mortgage or investment related. My HS math make me guess that all the COUPON  type functions are bond related. I could not find one that did compound interest nicely with my limited search

Comment: Who knows, you did a great job explaining. I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @ScottCraner You will need to organise your followers (aka lackey's aka findwindow) to assist with the voting 8)

Comment: @ScottCraner I think the only thing I prefer about this approach is my very last paragraph on the side note.  The results are independent compered the your solution where its a dependent series.

Comment: I agree that is why the simplest approach is usually the best.  I really depends on what is desired as an output.  My second approach though could be modified to use the month instead of the counter also.